# JavaFX add margin to Rectangle shape

Tags: java, javafx

In the following layout, how can I add right margin for each rectangle. For example, is there any method that allows to add margin?

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.BLACK);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.GREEN);
        Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.YELLOW);

        hBox.getChildren().addAll(rect1, rect2, rect3);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @Phil Freihofner, you can set spacing using `hBox.setSpacing()` and margin using static method `HBox.setMargin()`:

```
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.BLACK);
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.GREEN);
    Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.YELLOW);
    
    HBox hBox = new HBox(rect1, rect2, rect3);
    
    // Space between rectangles
    hBox.setSpacing(20);
    
    // Margins
    HBox.setMargin(rect1, new Insets(30, 0, 30, 30));
    HBox.setMargin(rect2, new Insets(30, 0, 30, 0));
    HBox.setMargin(rect3, new Insets(30, 30, 30, 0));
```

Output without setting spacing or margin:
[image]

Output setting spacing and margin:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

`HBox` has a *spacing* property for space between HBox elements. Is this sufficient?

https://api.javafx.dev/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#spacingProperty

You can also control the overall margin (using insets) for the HBox as a whole. With insets you can set just the right side, if that is the goal.

https://api.javafx.dev/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setMargin(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.geometry.Insets)

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear, I want to add margin to the rectangles (multiple rectangles are in a single Hbox. I don't find `setMargin` or  `setSpacing` for the rectangle.

Comment: @Jay the answer shows how to set the space between `Rectangles`: `hBox.setSpacing(10)`. If you want to set the margin to each `Rectangle`  you can use static method `HBox.setMargin(rect1, new Insets(10))`.

Comment: @Jay yes, those methods don't exist for `Shape` or its subclasses. You'd have to write a custom class. I'm not sure what the best wrapper would be, to make a paddable Rectangle. Maybe if there is only a single shape per pane, either an HBox or VBox is fine, as suggested by @Oboe's solution. Whether it's worth the trouble (to make a custom class) is another question.